# fullpage is not a constructor issue

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I always run into the same issue and currently i dont know a way out.
Following problem:

I try to use fullpage for my website. Here is a simplified version of what i am doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullpage.min.css">
</head>

<body>      
    <div id="fullpage">
        <section class="section" id="home">
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </section>
        
        <section class="section" id="project">
            <h2>Project</h2>
        </section>
        
        <section class="section" id="contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jsApplication.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullpage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Content of my "jsApplication.js":

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
              licenseKey: 'OPEN-SOURCE-GPLV3-LICENSE',
              autoScrolling: true,
});
```

I always get the following error: "TypeError: fullpage is not a constructor".
So what i am doing wrong?

best regards

Comment: Your order of scripts its incorrect, first you need to load your dependencies like jQuery and Fullpage. After that include your custom scripts. Right now you are trying to execute code that isn't loaded yet

Comment: Ok. That's embarrassing. Thank you so much.

Comment: better upvote the comment if you think that's helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

I found solution.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

is required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: didn't work for me